# Animate a cursor-image in html / css / javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

On my web page I would like to have an image where I animate a cursor over the image and then it presses on a "button" on the image. It's not a real button but rather just part of the image. I could do this animation by creating an animated gif but I prefer to keep the downloading data as small as possible and my image is on the order of 600x800, so animating with lots of gifs is kind of senseless.

An alternative would just be to have a png of some mouse cursor and possible animate it using javascript or even jquery.

I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: What kind of animation is it going to be? And yes, I would go for the animation option.

Comment: Simply move the cursor from point A to point B. Nothing fancy. Straigh line movement. What do you mean by "animation option"?

Comment: Well, then I would take the small PNG file, put it as an `img` in your HTML and animate with jQuery's `animate` function.